# MongoDB replicaset unable to read ssl/tls error - Mongodb enterprise operator in kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, ssl, openshift, mongodb-replica-set

I'm using MongoDB enterprise operator.
Created mongodb opsmanager.

Created MongoDB Resource with Mongodb CRD. Given below

```
apiVersion: mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDB
metadata:
  name: mongo-dev
  namespace: mongodb-workspace
spec:
  credentials: my-org-apikey
  members: 3
  opsManager:
    configMapRef:
      name: my-org-id
  type: ReplicaSet
   podSpec: 
     cpu: '4'
     memory: '6G'
  version: 5.0.18-ent
  security:
    tls:
      enabled: true
      ca: custom-ca
    authentication:
      enabled: true
      modes: ["SCRAM"]
```

Here are the steps I followed to create a self signed certificate.

1. openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
2. openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca.key -subj "/CN=*.svc.cluster.local" -days 3650 -reqexts v3_req -extensions v3_ca -out ca.crt
3. oc create secret tls ca-key-pair --cert=ca.crt --key=ca.key
4. oc apply -f cert-manager.yaml
5. oc apply -f issuers.yaml
6. oc apply -f certificates.yaml
7. oc get secret mongo-dev-0 -o jsonpath='{.data.tls.crt}{.data.tls.key}' | base64 --decode > mongo-dev-0-pem                                && \
8. oc get secret mongo-dev-1 -o jsonpath='{.data.tls.crt}{.data.tls.key}' | base64 --decode > mongo-dev-1-pem                                && \
9. oc get secret mongo-dev-2 -o jsonpath='{.data.tls.crt}{.data.tls.key}' | base64 --decode > mongo-dev-2-pem
10. oc create secret generic mongo-dev-cert --from-file=mongo-dev-0-pem --from-file=mongo-dev-1-pem --from-file=mongo-dev-2-pem
11. cat ca.crt > ca-pem
12. oc create configmap custom-ca --from-file=ca-pem
13. oc apply -f mongodb-rs.yaml

After mongodb replicaset reconilation, I'm getting error like.

Agent logs message is giving error

> Failed to apply action. Result =  : 
> [15:07:48.267] Error starting mongod :  [15:07:48.267]
> Error running start command.
> cmd=[Args=[/var/lib/mongodb-mms-automation/mongodb-linux-x86_64-5.0.18-ent/bin/mongod
> -f /data/automation-mongod.conf]], stip=[args={"net":{"bindIp":"0.0.0.0","port":27017,"tls":{"CAFile":"/mongodb-automation/tls/ca/ca-pem","allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates":true,"certificateKeyFile":"/mongodb-automation/tls/","mode":"preferTLS"}},"replication":{"replSetName":"mongodb-dev"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/data"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","path":"/var/log/mongodb-mms-automation/mongodb.log"}}[],confPath=/data/automation-mongod.conf,version=5.0.18-ent-796abe56bfdbca6968ff570311bf72d93632825b(enterprise),isKmipRotateMasterKey=false,useOldConfFile=false]

And I checked the pod terminal log, it shows.

sh-4.4$ cat /var/log/mongodb-mms-automation/mongodb.log

> {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-06T14:27:24.939+00:00"},"s":"E",
> "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23248,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Cannot read certificate
> file","attr":{"keyFile":"/mongodb-automation/tls/","error":"error:0909006C:PEM
> routines:get_name:no start line"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-06T14:27:24.941+00:00"},"s":"F",
> "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20574,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Error during global
> initialization","attr":{"error":{"code":140,"codeName":"InvalidSSLConfiguration","errmsg":"Can
> not set up PEM key file."}}}

For reference I followed this blog
https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/secure-mongo-db-enterprise-on-red-hat-openshift/#5-Generate-Certificates-and-enable-TLS

Can anyone help on this

Comment: Have a look at `"certificateKeyFile":"/mongodb-automation/tls/"` it does not specify any file, it is just a directory.

Comment: Thanks. 
Yes I too looked at it, but is there anyway to add the right keyfile to this directory ?